# Ping reply taking too long/not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, ping

When using Ping in correlation with PingReply to check the status of an IP Address and it's ports for and imported text list how do you launch a code to skip the current one and move onto the next one?

```
    PingReply reply = ping.Send("IP", "PORT");
```

Specifically

```
    PingReply reply = ping.Send("174.69.75.251", "41968");
```

There is no response at all, it just freezes the application so you cant check the reply status if its successful.

---

Going to a list of proxies I want to check if they're valid and able to be connected to a webBrowser1 control so I have the following code to send the request for the IP Address and Port to check if it will accept connections.

---

This is the whole code for the loop and everything, I have added what has been suggested by two people and excluded the TCPClient one with /* */ heres the code for the button:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    numberProx = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Lines.Length.ToString());
    proxyList = textBox1.Text.Split(new Char[] { '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    while (i < numberProx)
    {
        string currentProxy = proxyList[i++].ToString();
        try
        {/*
            TcpClient reply2 = new TcpClient();
            reply2.ConnectAsync(currentProxy.Split(':')[0],
                Convert.ToInt32(currentProxy.Split(':')[1]));

            if (reply2.Connected)
            {
                textBox2.AppendText(currentProxy + "\n");
            }
            else
            {
                textBox3.AppendText(currentProxy + "\n");
            }*/

            //PingReply reply = proxy.Send(currentProxy.Split(':')[0], Convert.ToInt32(currentProxy.Split(':')[1]));

            PingReply reply = await proxy.SendPingAsync("174.69.75.251", 5000);
            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                textBox2.AppendText(currentProxy + "\n");
            }
            else if (reply.Status == IPStatus.TimedOut)
            {

            }
            else if (reply.RoundtripTime >= 5000)
            {
                textBox3.AppendText(currentProxy + "\n");
            }
            else
            {
                textBox3.AppendText(currentProxy + "\n");
            }
        }
        catch (PingException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

That is everything including the loop and incremented integer to match the number of proxies in the string[] called proxyList.
What I want to do is see if the proxy is capable of working in a webBrowser control without the form/UI freezing.

Comment: What is the result when you ping directly from the console?

Comment: It classes it as a non working IP so it returns a time out on the IP Address.

Answer (score 2):

A ping request can't test an applicative PORT. For this, you have telnet.

The parameters taken by 'ping.Send' are:

```
ping.Send('IP_ADDRESS', 'TIMEOUT');
```

Like it is said in the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf697k33(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: With checking if both the IP and port's work in correlation do you have to use TcpClient.

Comment: Yes i was searching in MSDN and TcpClient seem to be a good way to do that you want.

Comment: I added code for what I am doing, how would you use TcpClient in the same mannor, you can use catch to check if there is no connection although I want it to launch code. I tried if(reply.Connected) { //do code } although it didn't connect to anything when I used TcpClient reply = new TcpClient(); reply.ConnectAsync("IP", "Port"); I used ConnectAsync so it doesn't freeze the application.

Comment: You can do like the following: 
`TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(); tcpClient.Connect("IP_ADDRESS", PORT); //or //tcpClient.ConnectAsync("IP_ADDRESS", PORT);
if(tcpClient.Connected) { //Do stuff } `

Comment: I did that at first but how do I use a if statement to check that the proxy is working and will work if I used it in a webBrowser1 windows for the connection outpost. I see how to establish the connection but returning if it is successful or not the way shown above returns everything as the same whereas pinging does not.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your last comment, but if you do this in a loop, you'll have to close the previous connection before trying a new one: `tcpClient.Close();`

Comment: My bad, I saw you included what I asked which was if (tcpClient.Connected) { //do code } i'll try that now. What I did previously was the same although I didn't include tcpClient.Close(); This is a proxy connection it is testing so theres no login or anything so this will check if it will work for direct connection to load web pages correct?

Answer (score 1):

You could specify a timeout using the overload of [Ping.Send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf697k33(v=vs.110).aspx) that accepts one. This takes the number of milliseconds to wait before timing out.

If you are in a UI application and this is causing your UI thread to freeze you could use the [asynchronous](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194139(v=vs.110).aspx) method and await the result. This would allow your UI to remain responsive while the request is being sent.

Comment: With the png responses I check if it's a success through reply.Status == IPStatus.Success and then reply.RoundtripTime to check if it takes too long, then just use else to check if anything else is wrong. However it doesn't skip to the next IP in the list, it just stays on that single IP and Port. Also with the Ping.SendPingAsync is it used in the same manor? It gave me the error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply>' to 'System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply

Comment: Sounds like there is possibly a problem in code you are not showing us. I suggest you update your question to include the part of your code that is actually looping. As for the async call error, I assume you are not awaiting the result which will unwrap the task.

Comment: I added the process code which preforms the loop, it continues until i = the exact number of lines. The loop works although when I added Async it did not. If i'm trying to do what I am doing what is better Ping or TcpClient to test it.

Comment: You need to call `PingReply reply = await proxy.SendPingAsync("174.69.75.251", 5000);`, but that would then require you to make your method an `async` method. Unfortunately your update still doesn't include your looping logic so it is still not possible to help further.

Comment: I added what the loop is exactly, theres a string which used the first one starting at 0 then i++ uses that value and increments by 1 for the next loop. What I have works (before Async) until the one working proxy where the whole application stops. I updated the SendPingAsync to what you had and received this error: The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

Comment: OK, this is my final comment as you don't seem to be listening too carefully to my advice. 1) Your loop code makes no sense - no where is `i` incremented, so your loop will never exit. 2) As I said above, you'll need mark your method as `async`. If you only implement part of what someone tells you you can't expect it to work. Good luck.

Comment: I added the entire process when the button is clicked to check if it works. I added everything you recommended alongside another which I excluded because it didn't work so I can check if yours work which it didn't. If you would be inclined to check over it do so and respond otherwise I'll try figure it out along the lines.